# What is the acceleration magnitude of a simple pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

I'm trying to find the acceleration vector of a simple pendulum. The vector is labeled *a* in this image from Wikipedia:

[image]

Trying to solve it, I've split the acceleration into perpendicular components: radial (along the string) and tangential (along the velocity vector). I've found that:

$a_\textrm{tangential} = d \ddot\theta$

$a_\textrm{radial} = d \dot\theta^2 + g \cos\theta$

where *d* is the length of the rod and *g* the acceleration from gravity. However, combining these two causes an awful expression, which makes me think that I've got something wrong:

$|a| = \sqrt{ a_\textrm{tangential}^2 + a_\textrm{radial}^2 } = \sqrt{ d^2 \ddot\theta^2 + ( d \dot\theta^2 + g \cos\theta )^2 }$

What is the actual magnitude of the acceleration vector of a simple pendulum?

My goal is to find an expression for the acceleration magnitude ($\sqrt{a_x^2+a_y^2+a_z^2}$) as measured by a three-axis accelerometer inside the bob.

**Edit:** I just realised that since $\ddot\theta = -\frac{g}{d}\sin\theta$, we can simplify:

$|a| = \sqrt{ d^2 \ddot\theta^2 + ( d \dot\theta^2 + g \cos\theta )^2 } = \sqrt{ g^2 + d^2\dot\theta^4 + 2dg\dot\theta^2 \cos\theta }$

Comment: Using $d$ for the length of the string is fairly confusing in a calculus context. I suggest using something else like $\ell$ or $r$.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Thanks! I used $l$ originally in a related question on dsp.SE and was recommended to use $d$ instead :)

Comment: I agree with BioPhysicist, but you do have to be careful to use a good font with $l$, or it can look like an $\text I$ or a 1.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you @PhilipWood!

Comment: My upvoted there is and I not know the reason.

Answer (score 2):

If $l$ is the pendulum length the radial acceleration is simply the centripetal acceleration
$$a_\text{rad}=l\dot\theta^2.$$
The tangential acceleration is, as you say,
$$a_\text{tan}=l\ddot\theta.$$
The expression for the resultant acceleration is not too bad if you are using the usual small angle approximations to treat the pendulum.

A nice little bit of trivia: for small angles:
Maximum tangential acceleration = $g\left(\frac Al\right)$
But maximum radial acceleration = $g\left(\frac Al\right)^2$
In which $A$ is the amplitude, measured as an arc length.

You ought not to have included $g\cos\theta$ in your expression for $a_\text{rad}$. In this context, $g$ is not an acceleration, but the gravitational field strength. So the radial force component on the pendulum bob is (Tension in thread – $mg \cos \theta$).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll see how it goes with the small-angle approximation. The reason I include the gravitational field strength is that the accelerometer does measure it. When at rest on my table, it will read 9.81 m/s^2 in z-direction. Do you think it makes sense to include *g* as I have done then, or is it still a mistake?

Comment: I just realised that it gets a bit simpler since $\ddot\theta = -\frac{g}{d}\sin\theta$, but still a hairy expression without the small-angle approximation.

Comment: "When at rest on my table, it will read 9.81 m/s^2 in z-direction". That's because accelerometers measure the acceleration relative to a body in freefall. In applying Newton's laws $for most purposes$ we use the Earth's surface as our reference frame, and treat bodies on its surface as having zero acceleration. The gravitational force on a body at rest on the Earth's surface is balanced by an equal and opposite force (if we neglect the body's small acceleration due to the Earth's diurnal rotation.

Comment: Thank you @PhilipWood! Apologies for causing confusion with the wrong terms. Then I guess I'm trying to find the acceleration magnitude of a simple pendulum, relative to freefall :)

Answer (score 1):

the position vector to the mass point is

$$\mathbf R=\begin{bmatrix}
  x(t) \\
  y(t) \\
\end{bmatrix}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} d\sin \left( \varphi  \left( t \right) 
 \right) \\ d\cos \left( \varphi  \left( t \right) 
 \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

from here you obtain the acceleration $\mathbf{\ddot{R}}$
$$\mathbf{\ddot{R}}=\begin{bmatrix}
  \ddot x(t) \\
  \ddot y(t) \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\left[ \begin {array}{c} d\cos \left( \varphi  \right) 
\ddot\varphi -d\sin \left( \varphi  \right) {\dot\varphi }^{2}
\\ -d\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \ddot\varphi -d
\cos \left( \varphi  \right) {\dot\varphi }^{2}\end {array} \right]
$$
substitute $\ddot\varphi=-\frac{g}{d}\,\sin(\varphi)$ from the equation of motion and obtain the magnitude $~a=\sqrt{\ddot x(t)+\ddot y(t)}$

$$a=\sqrt { \left( \sin \left( \varphi  \right)  \right) ^{2}{g}^{2}+{d}^{
2}{\dot\varphi }^{4}}
$$

Comment: Thank you, neat approach! In order to include the "acceleration" due to gravity (which is also measured by my accelerometer), I'll simply add find $\sqrt{\ddot{x}^2 + (\ddot{y} + g)^2}$, right?

Comment: This is correct

Comment: Why in this community are there few up votes? My it is +1

Comment: @Sebastiano I was also confused! I upvoted it and later it was back to zero. Someone also downvoted my question.

Comment: It's comforting to see that squaring and adding the radial and tangential accelerations from my answer (and using $\ddot \theta=-\frac gl \sin \theta$) gives the same answer as Eli's ! [That's if we use the usual convention for acceleration!]

Comment: The magnitude must be equal, because it is scalar

Comment: Yes. I simply meant that no mistakes have shown up!